# Does akka-streams support clustering ? If yes, Please share example

Tags: akka-stream, akka-cluster

I am using akka stream in my application to handle realtime data.
Data volume is so high so I want to horizontally scale my application. 
Can some help me to understand does akka-streams support clustering ?  If yes,  Please share example.

Answer (score 0):

I have found no examples or documentation that would indicate `akka-stream` is capable of directly running in a clustered mode.  However, there are a few "work-arounds" that you may be able to deploy.

**Integration with Akka Cluster**

You could have a `Flow.map` or `Flow.mapAsync` send an incoming object to the cluster and wait for the response.

**Sharding of Incoming Data**

The source data could be broken up by a sharding function and sent to independent services which process the data in parallel.  Each service could operate with a single `akka-stream` but the cluster of applications would allow for multiple streams running independently.